# Iterating through a database in Node and fixing to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to iterate through a database and add the values to an array in Node.js. When I try to push the items based on their column name ('account name':res.rows[i].account_name), I get an "undefined" error.

If I push the item in with the "accountList.push(res.rows[i])" line, all the data goes into the object but it isn't labelled.

I have a feeling that this is something to do with the async nature of Node.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const query = {
   name: "getDB",
   text: "select * from smartsneakers",
   rowMode:'array',
    }    
pool.query(query, (err,res) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({"status_code": 500, "status_message": "internal server error"});
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                console.log(res.rows[i].account_name)
                //accountList.push(res.rows[i]);
                var account = {
                    'account name':res.rows[i].account_name,

                }
                accountList.push(account);
            }
            //console.log(accountList);
            console.log(accountList[0]);
            
        }
    })

//close connection
pool.end();
```

Comment: Can you add the log for res before for loop

Comment: It outputs all of the data in the console, it's all loaded up:   
fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 16561,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'parent_account',
      tableID: 16561,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 25,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'

Comment: now you can see there is no field named account_name

Comment: account_name was in the next response, there were 2 columns before it and I only put a partial response in the comment

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was using "rowMode:'array'" so it was outputting the whole row.

The question led me to the answer - thanks!

Comment: Code is available here: https://github.com/lowkeysam/psql_to_node